# Not able to access the JSON string outside of the PHP function?

Tags: php, json, function, scope

I am curling a JSON string within a PHP function called curl_pair($json_pair_filename). var_dump correctly shows the data within the function so the data exists within the function, but I am not able to access the JSON string outside of the PHP function. What should I change?

```
    if(curl_exec($ch) === false)
    { // Curl error:
        //echo '<a target="_blank" href="http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html">' . curl_error($ch) . "</a>";
        include( DOMAIN_PATH . "tickers/form_curl_error.php");
        $my_data = "something went wrong...";
    }
    else // fetch the data
    {
        $my_data = curl_multi_getcontent ( $ch );
        //var_dump($my_data);   // is ok shows json string
        curl_close( $ch );
    }
    return json_encode($my_data);
}
curl_pair($json_pair_filename); // no errors

echo($my_data); // just a white screen, no data, no nothing.
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to be capturing the output of your function, or nesting the function call inside your echo.  I'm not a PHP developer, but in most programming languages variables declared inside functions are private to the function, so $my_data doesn't exist outside.  But your are returning it from your function, so

```
$result_data = curl_pair($json_pair_filename);
echo($result_data);
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

Please try executing following code snippet.

In the above code snippet ,the scope of $my_data variable was within the function in which it was set.
To make it accessible outside function you need to return value at point where that function was invoked.

```
 if(curl_exec($ch) === false)
    { // Curl error:
        //echo '<a target="_blank" href="http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html">' . curl_error($ch) . "</a>";
        include( DOMAIN_PATH . "tickers/form_curl_error.php");
        $my_data = "something went wrong...";
    }
    else // fetch the data
    {
        $my_data = curl_multi_getcontent ( $ch );
        //var_dump($my_data);   // is ok shows json string
        curl_close( $ch );
    }
    return json_encode($my_data);
}
$my_data=curl_pair($json_pair_filename); // no errors

echo($my_data); // just a white screen, no data, no nothing.
```

Comment: Thank you Rubin you are correct, it is a question of variable scope. Appreciate the response.